# MySQL require multiple values from multiple rows of a join

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the following table structures.

Table A

```
id    name
1     name1
2     name2
```

Table B

```
a_id   b_id
1      1
1      2
```

How can I select all rows of table A that have both a b_id of 1 and 2? Table B is a mapping table between table A and another table, whose contents do not matter for this question.

Thank you for your time and help!

Comment: What SQL have you tried?

Comment: I love the diversity of the answers below. Thank you everyone for posting. I'm slowly reading through them and implementing them before I choose an answer.

Comment: So, in your example, you want the row where id = 1 from Table A?

Comment: @prodigitalson I'm no SQL guru, so my first attempt makes little sense. I did a join and used AND to check for both ids. Alas, one row wouldn't have both. After some searching, I discovered the IN syntax, though it doesn't force the use of both ids within the mapping table. One solution below uses the IN syntax with order by and count, which I feel is clever, provided it works, which I'll see. :)

Comment: @MarcusAdams I'm looking for all the rows of table A that has two rows from table B with the values of 1 and 2 (for b_id). Table B a_id would naturally reference id of Table A. Hope that makes more sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This query uses `COUNT(DISTINCT)` to ensure the presence of both values. If I did not use DISTINCT it may incorrectly count rows in TableB that look like this as a match when it shouldn't:

```
a_id   b_id
1      1
1      1  


select a.id, a.name
from TableA a
inner join (
    select a_id
    from TableB
    where b_id in (1, 2)
    group by a_id
    having count(distinct b_id) = 2 #this number matches no. of unique values in IN clause
) b on a.id = b.a_id
```

[SQL Fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/777b9/1)

Comment: @RedFilter nice but you should include some comment on why correctness can be tricky. e.g. the need for `count(distict b_id) = 2` vs `count(b_id) = 2)`

Comment: My question is a small piece of a much larger problem. Essentially I have 8 mapping tables, just like table B that can have 1-7(ish) values (like b_id). My users are able to sort the data by selecting checkboxes, which I use to determine what rows to display. Using your solution, would I run into performance issues dealing with numerous tables? I definitely like the simplicity of your answer and feel I can program it for all eight mapping tables. Just looking for your opinion. Thanks!

Comment: Without seeing the schema, data, and query in question, it is hard to make any call on performance. But I don't know a better way than the above technique on MySQL. Best approach: try it and see.

Comment: @Akaishen, be sure to try my answer too. Often, joins perform better than temporary derived tables (sub queries) because joins can utilize indexes. Of course, this assumes you have the proper indexes.

Comment: @MarcusAdams My primary reason for liking this answer is how easy it'll be to program for all 8 mapping tables and two dependent tables. In all honesty, though, I've learned quite a bit from all answers and appreciate the time and help from all users. If I run into performance issues, I'll definitely give your solution a try. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Correctness can be tricky on a question like this because your sample data is missing a key cases. Duplicate values for B_ID and the possibility that it can contain one of the ids but not both

e.g.

```
| A_ID | B_ID |
---------------
|    1 |    1 |
|    1 |    2 |
|    2 |    1 |
|    2 |    1 |
```

The best approach is to use Having (Distinct Count) = # of ids ([RedFilter's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11196812/119477)) since its easy to add more ID's

The two other options are to use or multiple EXISTS or IN clauses  ([NickB's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11196896/119477)) or to join and filter multiple times (below) but can become tortuously long if you need to add additional ids.

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.id,
       a.name
FROM TableA a
     INNER JOIN TableB b1
     ON a.id = b1.a_id
        and b1.b_id = 1
    INNER JOIN TableB b2
     ON a.id = b2.a_id
        and b2.b_id = 2
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/52b44/1)

Comment: I don't recommend this approach: as soon as your list of values grows, you need to add more joins (one more for each additional value), and performance will quickly become an issue.

Comment: @RedFilter but you already took the good one but fine I'll make it clearer

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM A JOIN B ON A.id=B.a_id WHERE B.b_id IN(1,2);
```

Comment: table B in this query is actually the mapping table, otherwise correct :)

Comment: @ImreL true but does it matter? You would prefer it written with B being the primary table?

Comment: @ImreL you're mistaken this will produce a false positive for A.ID = 2 if table B has just one of the values e.g. (2,1) [here's an example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4937e/1).

Comment: @LmreL perhaps you misread the question "How can I select all rows of table A that have **both a b_id of 1 and 2**" This query selects all the rows of table A that have **either 1 or 2**

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I could come up with, it uses one subquery.

```
SELECT * FROM table_a a1 
    JOIN table_b b1
    ON a1.id = b1.a_id 
WHERE b1.b_id = 1 AND 
    EXISTS( 
        SELECT b2.b_id 
            FROM table_b b2 
        WHERE a1.id = b2.a_id 
            AND b2.b_id = 2
    )
```

Didn't know SQL Fiddle exists, but [here is one](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a4393/3) showing it working!

Comment: I don't recommend this approach: as soon as your list of values grows, you need to add more EXISTS subqueries (one more for each additional value), and performance will quickly become an issue.

Comment: I never said it was the most efficient :) Then again, the OP never said the list of IDs was dynamic either.

Answer (score 1):

I'll take a stab at this too, with a self join:

```
SELECT A.* FROM B B1
JOIN B B2 ON B2.a_id = B1.a_id
JOIN A ON A.id = B1.a_id
WHERE B1.b_id = 1 AND B2.b_id = 2
```

I tested this, and it works. If (B.a_id, B.b_id) isn't unique, then you'll need DISTINCT to avoid duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TableA.* FROM TableA WHERE TableA.id IN(
SELECT TableB.a_id FROM TableB WHERE TableB.b_id IN(1,2))
```